# Formatting parts of labels in an automatically generated legend in QGIS in italics?

Tags: qgis, legend, layouts

I'm working on a legend in QGIS where I'm customizing the labels for different categories. I'd like to format parts of the labels in italics, such as representing the translation of a term in parentheses in italics. Here's an example of how the labels look:

[x] Example (engl.: example)
[y] Example (engl.: example)
[z] Example (engl.: example)

where [x],[y] and [z] are symbols.

How can I italicize specific parts of the label, for example, "example" and "engl." in parentheses? Is it even possible in QGIS? Perhaps with html styling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the label settings > `Text` tab, check the box `Allow HTML formatting` and add a text string representing a html formatting like this:

```
'Example <i>(engl.: example)</i>'
```

Here with *italic* and additional **bold** text:
[image]

You can do the same for legend labels. In the legend's `Item Properties`, go to `Fonts and Text Formatting`, go to `Item Labels` and click on `Item Font` . There, you can check the box `Allow HTML formatting`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! For clarification: The HTML - Text renderer in the Legend in the print layout only works from Version 3.30 upwards.