Using HTML legend in QGIS - need clarity
Apparently, there is a new tool for using HTML rendering in QGIS print layout, legend. It has been specified here: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/#print-layouts under Feature: add super and subscript support for text renderer.
In my legend, I have a feature called 'Area Boundary' so from what I understand, all I have to do is click legend - Item properties - Legend items - 'area boundary' - and this leaves you in the text entry box for this label by which now I can change the name to anything. So again, from what I understand, using QGIS 3.34.5, I now enter Area Boundary <sub>LicenceArea 24.4.24 </sub> and that it should appear as subscript : Area Boundary LicenceArea 24.4.24 . This is not the case and it just appears as it has been typed. I can't find anything online to help describe this process.

The "Allow HTML formatting" check box is well hidden for legend element this answer will let you find it : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469121/formatting-parts-of-labels-in-an-automatically-generated-legend-in-qgis-in-itali
